# obtain name of the object in json object using jquery .each

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json object like this

```
["items"]=>
    ["apple"]=>
             ["id"]=> "1234"
             ["price"]=> "1"
    ["pear"]=>
             ["id"]=> "4322"
             ["price"]=> "2"
    ["banana"]=>
             ["id"]=> "345"
             ["price"]=> "1"
```

However, I do not know each item name when retrieving, how can I access the items and get the names, apple, pear, banana and display its properties(id & price).

Normally I i know the name, I would just use items.apple.id or items.apple.pear

```
$.each(items, function(){
     console.log(this.apple.id);
});
```

The jquery .each example above shows if I know the name, but what If i do not its apple, I want to list all the items?

Comment: could you provide the real JSON format? -- cannot figure out what is array and what is hash-map. (btw. what format is it?)

Comment: i just want to illustrate it.

Comment: @edward your illustration is confusing, since you appear to be showing a triple nested object, rather than an object named `items` that contains a double nested object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$.each(items, function(ind,val){
     console.log(val.id);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn4kj/)

Answer (score 0):

When called on an object, `$.each` will pass each `key` and `value` as parameters to the supplied function:

```
$.each(items, function(key, value) {
    console.log(items[key].id);    // or value.id
});
```

Note that per the comment in the code the `value` field will be the inner nested object, so you could just access its fields directly (i.e. `value.id`).  I've used `items[key]` to show more explicitly what parameters are being passed, since you specifically said you wanted to know the object's name.

Comment: great, i will test it out

Comment: should i use items or `this`?

Comment: You should use items.

"value" would be the item name "apple, pear ...", items[key].id the "apples id, pears id..." and items[key].type the "apples type, pears type..."